# Qt Creator crashes loading Examples

Tags: qt, qt-creator

There is an Example tab at the Qt Creator(2.6.1)'s Welcome page, which is supposed to show the already made Qt Project Examples. But whenever I click on that, Qt creator closes automatically. Sometimes it shows the Example projects for 1 or 2 seconds and the exits. Any idea?

Comment: Your system version would be helpful, and you could also try installing 2.7 version.

Comment: My system configuration:
HP Probook 4331s
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2430M CPU @2.40GHz
4.00 GB Ram
Windows 7 Professional64 bit
Qt 5.0.0 (32 bit)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to configure Qt Creator to find your Qt installation.

[Compiler configuration for Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979885/compiler-configuration-for-qt-creator)

And you might need to get the msvs compiler, too.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

They now have the mingw version available for windows with Qt 5.0.2.

http://qt-project.org/downloads

Also if you installed Qt without the examples that may also cause this error.

Hope that helps.