# Configure enviroment variables for qt and visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, qt

I've installed: Visual Studio 2010.
qt-windows-opensource-5.1.0-msvc2010-x86-offline
and
qt-vs-addin-1.2.2-opensource

All worked fine, i was able to use qt creator, to create applications and compile and run it.

But i've modified original path from enviroment variables:
http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/382/nh4e.png

And now when try to run application with qt creator i'm getting this error:

```
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
jom: C:\C++\Qt\build-tesst-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\mainwindow.obj] Error 1
jom: C:\C++\Qt\build-tesst-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
20:54:01: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project tesst (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 MSVC2010 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

I've already read dozens of thread on internet but nothing, i've already reinstalled qt-windows-opensource-5.1.0-msvc2010-x86-offline
and
qt-vs-addin-1.2.2-opensource

but still the same error.

Later edit: Programs won't run only from qt creator. If i'm importing qt project on visual studio 2010 it work to compile and run the application.

Comment: Did you read following link ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Yes, i've set environment variables but still same error.

Comment: add path to "toolchain" manualy "tools->options->Build&Run"

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand. Where to add path on Build&Run?

Comment: Ok first check, "Projects" tab, whether Qt version is updated or not. If not then you need to add compiler(binary) to the toolchan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modified original path variable from environment, Auto-detect of QtCreator toolchange doesnt may not detecte the compiler( your case VS compiler). So to fix this issue, you need either update path variable correctly or add vs compiler manualy to the toolchane and Build. you can try with MinGw compiler too.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem. But i don't know how to add this. Look, this is my configuration: http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/9649/adkf.png . when move mouse over the kit say: "Warning: No debuger set up". What i don't know is how to add compiler

Comment: @curuosul I don't have, dev environment to confrm this, may be this link is useful for your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979885/compiler-configuration-for-qt-creator.

Comment: @curiosul Let’s first try to get it to compile before we get into debugging (. To add it manually you’ll have to know where you installed the MSVC2010 compiler. I think the easiest for you would be to take the auto-detected MSVC2010 settings( Your working senario), clone them and change the paths so that they point to 2010. Moreovere confirm VS debugger is installed, and set the path.

Comment: I've been uninstalled vs and reaplaced with visual studio 2012 and qt with Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 525 MB), I've installed mingw too and still the same problem...and I can't understand what you say above.

Comment: Pls check this link too http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-tool-chains.html. I think this is more useful

Comment: I've not sure what i've donne but I think your link helps me and now works. Thank you. Solved

Comment: That is great, At least you managed to fix. Any way I am still working on finding exact issue, .Will update you once i got break through..