# Configure compiler for Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I just downloaded "Qt 5.5.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2013, 823 MB)" from http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/

When I ran build, I got this error:

```
error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options.
```

There is no compiler for me to select in the Debug Computer Icon on the left. [Compiler configuration for Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979885/compiler-configuration-for-qt-creator)

I'm running a 64-bit Windows 10.

Comment: Did you install Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I have VS Community 2015 installed

Comment: You need to match the version of compiler expected by Qt. In this case, you'll need VS 2013, not 2015. I don't think Qt even has releases for VS 2015 out yet.

Comment: Can I just download this https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx?

Comment: Yes. Just make sure you get 2013. Community/Enterprise/etc. shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Oh there wasn't a sublink. I meant the sublink: Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013

Comment: I don't think so. You'll likely need the entire VS 2013, instead of 2015.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98996/discussion-between-owacoder-and-user3918985).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must download and install Visual studio 2013 before install `Qt 5.5.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2013, 823 MB)`

Answer (score 0):

This because you did not install a compiler.You need to download a compiler,Visual studio and MingW are both OK.

Comment: Please provide more information in your answer, to enrich its content